# Как вызвать данную функцию?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    textBox2.Text = cez(textBox2.Text);
    pictureBox1.Image = picture();//здесь необходимо вызвать функцию

    // textBox2.Text = Replace();
}

// здесь происходит чтение каждого символа в строке,
// а затем вызов функций, которые выполняют рисование
public Image picture(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    string str = textBox2.Text; 

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '1':
                white(sender,e);
                break;
            case '0':
                black(sender,e);
                break;

        }
    }

    return Image;
}

public void white(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(0, 100); 
    int y = random.Next(0, 100);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, x, y, 1, 1);
}

public void black(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(0, 100);
    int y = random.Next(0, 100);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91986/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посоветую пойти через другой путь. Перепишем метод (параметр с типом `EventArgs`, а не `PaintEventArgs` при клике на кнопку):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = cez(textBox2.Text);

    // Заставить форму перерисовываться вместе с изображением (вызовется метод OnPaint)
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

По-хорошему, нужно хранить признак типа `Boolean` в приватных филдах формы, чтобы пониамть, что Вы вызвали рисование при нажатии на кнопку. Далее перегрузим метод рисования:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   // Не забываем вызвать базовый метод, чтобы перерисовалась форма
   base.OnPaint(e);

   // Вызываем ваш самописный метод и передаем в него PaintEventArgs 
   pictureBox1.Image = picture(e);
}
```

Метод немного упростится (убираем `object sender`):

```
public Image picture(PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    string str = textBox2.Text; 

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '1':
                white(e);
                break;
            case '0':
                black(e);
                break;
        }
    }

    return Image;
}
```

Ну и из двух дпугих методов убираем ненужный параметр:

```
public void white(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(0, 100); 
    int y = random.Next(0, 100);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, x, y, 1, 1);
}

public void black(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(0, 100);
    int y = random.Next(0, 100);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, 1, 1);
}
```

Получить из `EventArgs` тип `PaintEventArgs` не получится, зато можно инициировать отправку сообщения рисования элементу управления. Почитать про инересный метод можно тут: [`Control.Invalidate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Все, наверное, верно, но ошибка все равно осталась. Тип Image почему-то не подходит

Comment: мда... и все это только ради того, чтобы оставить `PaintEventArgs`

Comment: @АнтонРябухин ну конечно же не подходит. У вас же там метод возвращает... как бы так сказать - ничего, просто тип. Я показал вам, как можно обойти ту ошибку, что у вас в вопросе. Из  `EventArgs` получить `PaintEventArgs`